# How i can flush input data of this modal?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this modal:

```
<div class="modal-dialog"> 
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Sei sicuro di voler eliminare questa applicazione?</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group" id="applicazione">
                <label>Applicazione:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="applicazione-input">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="dimensione">
                <label> Dimensione:</label>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group" id="creationDate">
                <label>Data inserimento richiesta:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="descStatoCaricamento">
                <label>Stato Caricamento:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="dataCaricamentoSulCubo">
                <label>Data caricamento sul cubo:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="esito">
                <label>Esito:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"  id="note">
                <label>Note:</label>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to delete only the data content of inputs when I dismiss the modal, how can I do that? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
    $(".modal-body").html("");
});
```

However it doesn't work properly because it deletes everything in my modal.

Comment: `I want to delete only the data content of <div id="">` Uhhhh, which div exactly?

Comment: And you have duplicate IDs everywhere which will not work. They must be unique on a page.

Comment: "Data" is the plural of "datum". "Datas" isn't a word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you are trying to delete the html from the inner `div's` of your divs inside the modal-body`

**Solution:**
You can use the `>` selector on the div's to select the direct decedents of it and remove the content. See the below example.

```
$(".modal-body div.form-group > div").html("");
```

Also you have duplicate id's in your HTML, which is not right.

**Id's in HTML should be unique, Else as a alternative use `class`**

As mentioned above remove the duplicate id's. As a example your HTML must change to

```
<div class="form-group" id="applicazione">
 <label>Applicazione:</label>
  <div></div>                            <!-- removed the id -->
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you, i know duplicate IDs it's not a good coding, but i needed to do some operation at the same time on both part..

Comment: @DarioS glad I could help.

Comment: `i needed to do some operation at the same time on both part` have class names for this task..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#model').empty();
```

Here #model is the id of your model, and .empty() will remove full html content from DOM.